# Kudu reports no local storage left for Azure Functions Premium app

Tags: azure-functions, kudu

there's our function app in a premium service plan. This has 21 GB local storage included. Shortly after starting the app, Kudu reports that only 8MB are remaining.

This is odd. How can I check what files specifically are using up that space so quickly?

The quotas section on the portal does not show any utilisation at all, so that's not helpful.

Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have created 2 functions apps one without publishing any function or files and in another we have published and uploaded files and found that the space is getting occupied due to log files that are being logged for every activity.

Storage usage with Functions and files:
[image]

Here are the screenshots which states where the files are consuming the storage.

- Navigate to the storage account of your function app > File Shares > File
- From here you can navigate to different folders and check for the size of your folders and files
  [image]

Here is the screenshot of my functions (PATH: Your associate storage account > File shares > your file share > data > functions > sample data > whatever the functions you're deployed to azure function app, those activity data will be logged)
[image]

Here is the screenshot of my logs (PATH: Your associated storage account >File Shares > Your File Share Account > Log Files > Kudu > trace > activity logs)
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Though I think that storage shows the D:\home storage which is mounted. The problem I experienced was with the D:\local folder, this will be on the worker VM OS drive that is currently running the app. I have not yet found a way of monitoring that space out-of-the-box. Therefore I dedicated a single function to do a recursive dir listing and put the file metadata onto blob storage, so I can evaluate this.

Comment: Exactly that's the reason why your local storage is getting accumulated. You can check the accumulated storage and its logs from the storage account like I have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: You mean once the file share for D:/home exceeds storage capacity (5 TB) it then spills over to D:/local? I have checked the file sizes withn the D:\home file share, these are negligible.