How can I associate a storage account to get the logs files of an azure app service from kudu?
I'm looking to associate/link a storage account to get the logs files from Kudu of an azure app service. Is there a way to do this? or is it possible ?
I have checked the settings and wiki of kudu plus but found no luck.

Configure Diagnostic settings under Azure App Service to send the logs to the storage account.
Navigate to App Service=> Monitoring, select Diagnostic settings => Add diagnostic setting=> Archive to Storage Account.

Select the desired log categories to export.


Stores the App Service logs in Storage Container:

If your App Service is Windows,
You can enable Application logging(Blob) (or) Application logging(File System)  under Web App=>Monitoring=>App Service Logs to send the logs to Storage Container:

Create or select the desired Blob Storage, the Container and the Level of logging.


Refresh the Container to check the logs:

It stores the logs in Storage account:


Thank you so much for this information. However, what I'm after is getting the kudu log files to be saved/copy to a storage account. More like in this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70133425/kudu-reports-no-local-storage-left-for-azure-functions-premium-app.
